# ¿Reajustar autoincrementable int en mySQL phpAdmin?

Tags: mysql

muy buenas una ayuda el problema que tengo es en un crud programado en php codeigniter 4 con conexión a base de datos que registra edita y elimina usuarios, al realizar el borrado de los mismos y volver a añadir uno nuevo el contador se continua incrementando como si el id anterior no se haya eliminado  ejemplo

- 1 juan
- 2 lucas
- 3 eliminado-->pedro
- 4 jhon
  lo que deseo es que el id de jhon deje de ser 4 sino sustituir al id de pedro es decir
- 1 juan
- 2 lucas
- 3 jhon
  muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Por defecto el `AUTO_INCREMENT` de MySQL es asi, descozco si es posible hacer ese cambio que quieres dentro de la BD. Por lo que podrias hacerlo manualmente en tu codigo(Basicamente un correlativo)

Answer (score -2):

Lo que tienes que hacer es un Truncate a tu tabla para que el contador se vuelva a la posición inicial que es 0.

```
truncate table TABLA;
```

Después de hacer eso, asegurate de poner el id autoincrement y te quedará. Solo debes de meter los registros.

Comment: ¿Podrías mejorar y ampliar tu aporte?, por ejemplo ¿cómo funcionará dado el contexto del OP?

Comment: Claro, en tu phhMyAdmin hay una opción que se llama "SQL". dale clic y ahí haz el truncate que te mencioné arriba (sentencia SQL), luego solamente seleccionas tu id que quieres hacer auto-incrementable y busca la casilla "auto-increment", la seleccionas y debe de funcionarte.

Comment: `Truncate` no es la manera correcta, lo que hará será borrar toda la data y no la organizaría: The MySQL TRUNCATE TABLE statement allows you to delete all data in a table.

Comment: -1. Como bien comenta  @FranciscoNúñez [truncate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html) te borra todos los datos de una tabla-

Comment: Eso mismo especifiqué, que debía volver a poner los registros, con la solución que le di, evitará próximos errores de ID.